# How to run Razor function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net, razor, .net-core

My razor function in my index.cshtml

```
@functions{
public void FillTheList(){
//some part of code
}
}
```

I need to run FillTheList()-same cshtml with - function

```
<script>
@{
FillTheList();
}
</script>
```

Javascript cannot run FillTheList() function this code.How to i fix it

Comment: Hey more... i have expanded my answer which will hopefully help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused. Razor is C# html templating syntax that runs on a web server. Javascript is a code which runs on a users browser. You can use Razor to write JavaScript out, just the same as you can use notepad to write javascript.

Comment: I dont need return value.I just need run this func.But it didn't.I think this solution is not working

Comment: I am just giving you an example.
What do you want your method to do? P.S func is a kind of C# delegate.

Comment: Exactly what @Harry said. Razor is an engine which allows you to create HTML using C# syntax. The Razor engine takes the cshtml file in your view and produces the resulting HTML which is sent to the browser as the response body. As such, the Razor syntax will be replace with HTML before it is served by your web-server.